# Number of processes called espeak

Tags: 12.04, process

running 12.04 on an ltsp network.  A number of users seem to have a large number of espeak processes running, yet they seem to using LibreOffice and not consciously using any speech synthesis

Answer (score 1):

In a default Ubuntu installation **espeak** may have been activated by turning on the screen reader from the [accessibility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility) tool **Orca**.

In case you have issues with this you may have to disable the screen reader from Orca or educate your users not to use it.